# How to call different version of Internet explorer option in F12 developer tools from Windows command line

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-7, ie-developer-tools

I need to have multiple versions of IE browser in my windows 7 for cross browser testing. 
I checked for Standalone application,  but nothing worked properly.

I know there is a F12 developer tool in windows which will switch the user agent, is it possible to call the iexplore.exe browser from command line along with the required browser version?

- I have already got the trial version of spoon, but I am looking for a free solution.
- I am not looking for any paid version of alternatives
- I dont need procedures that involve creation of virtual machine as they will not work for me.

Kindly let me know if the above information is not clear or insufficient.

Comment: Any help on this or is the question not clear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the browser version from the command line.

The closest you can do and it's not at all recommend as it impacts every IE instance is to use the Browser Emulation feature control key ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to change the default mode.

Comment: thats a brilliant approach andy. But I went to the mentioned location in regedit and tried all the combination in terms of decimal and hexadecimal, but i could nt find it working. Initially I did not have contoso.exe and I newly added one and then passed the value. Secondly, I am not sure how to check the same, hence i left the developer tool enabled and every time I changed it , it shows me the same. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARE->Microsoft->Internet Explorer ->Main ->FeatureControl -> FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
                     contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00009000

Comment: You need to add the value of your exe (specifically the image name as it appears in task manager) not the generic contoso.exe. If you want it to impact IE you need to set it iexplore.exe.